# Setting the Value attribute of HTML input tags by calling php method with return value

Tags: php, html

So I want to set the value attribute of an html form to the return value of a method, But it isnt letting me. It works if I use `$_POST["text"]`, but not this way...:

```
<?php

class eventhandler
{
    public $text;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->text = $_POST["text"];  
    }

    public function getText()
    {
        return $this->text;
    }
}


if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $ev1 = new eventhandler();
}


?>

<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" autocomplete="on">
    <input type="text" name="text" value="<?php echo $ev1->getText(); ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

<?php 
echo $ev1->getText();
?>
```

Thank...im not sure if it isnt allowed or im doing something wrong!

Comment: Unfortunately not! Just a blank page...I have Display Errors on in the php.ini file in my MAMP bin directory as well...

Comment: Blank page, you can't even see your form ?

Comment: Yup. no form or anything...

Comment: Just look at the source of your blank page: `PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getText() on a non-object` when you don't do a POST request.

Comment: Check your server's error log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the `$ev1` variable may or may not be defined.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $ev1 = new eventhandler();
    // Because $ev1 is defined inside this IF block it will
    // only be defined if the expression evaluates to TRUE
    // If it is not a POST request then it will not be existent here
}
// $ev1 is NOT existent here if it is e.g. a GET request
```

If you use `$ev1` outside the `if` block, like this:

```
... value="<?php echo $ev1->getText(); ?>" />
```

Then you will get an error that looks something like this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getText() on a non-object

To fix this problem the `$ev1` object needs to always be defined.

Comment: That’s no true – `if` does not establish it’s own scope in PHP.

Comment: This is actually the problem but the explanation is wrong. When `$ev1` is not defined (when no POST is made), you get a `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getText() on a non-object`.

Comment: Agreed – but that is something different than initially stated here.

Comment: @CBroe: Yeah, I did not explain it very well. I have reworded the answer.

Comment: Make that code comment “NOT visible here” an “not _existent_ here” instead, then I’ll be satisfied too ;-)

Comment: Oh OK I see what the problem is thanks for the clarification. And sorry about asking about such a trivial problem im rather new to coding. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

You aren't really using objects how they are supposed to be used. You should be using something like this:

```
class eventhandler{
            public $text;

            public function __construct(){

            }

            public function setText($text) {
                $this->text = $text;
            }


            public function getText(){
                return $this->text;
            }
        }


        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        $ev1 = new eventhandler();
            $ev1->setText($_POST['text']);
```